# Is it possible to display more than one node in a page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display two nodes in Drupalgap.

```
//page_callback
function tung_intro_page() {
  var display_page = '<body>' + '<div id="my_node_13"></div>'; 
  display_page += '<div id="my_node_3"></div>' + '</body>';
  return display_page;
}

function tung_intro_pageshow() {
//  drupalgap_alert('My pageshow event has been called!');
 try{
        var nid = 13;
        node_load(nid, {
        success:function(node){
         var title = node.title;
         var content = node.content;
         //var whole = html(title) + html(content);
         $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');
          }
        });
        nid = 3;
        node_load(nid, {
        success:function(node){
         var title = node.title;
         var content = node.content;
         $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');
          }
        });
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('tung_intro_pageshow - ' + error); }
}
```

This only shows the content of the last node. How can I show both the nodes?

Comment: What if you place the second call to `node_load()` inside the first call's `success` handler? Essentially load the first node, wait for it and inject it, then retrieve the second node, wait for it and inject it. Not necessarily ideal, but probably a quick work around. Otherwise, look into tthis issue too: https://www.drupal.org/node/2601764

Comment: Thank you very much. It works when I put my second node_load() into the end of my 1st success handler.

Comment: However, an interesting new problem is, I have other hook menu doing the same thing and node_load() the same node. It won't display correctly when one has been called. Is it true that node_load() can only load a node once?(other module cannot load the same node again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comment conversation...

Try this in your `pageshow` handler:

```
function tung_intro_pageshow() {

  // Load the fist node and inject it.
  var nid = 13;
  node_load(nid, {
    success:function(node) {

      var title = node.title;
      var content = node.content;
      $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');

      // Load the second node node and inject it.
      nid = 3;
      node_load(nid, {
          success:function(node){

            var title = node.title;
            var content = node.content;
            $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');

          }
      });

    }
  });
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but a workaround nonetheless. A more ideal solution is dependent on the outcome of this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2601764